# Como mostrar todos os marcadores?

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo Ionic onde preciso mostrar vários pontos no mapa do Google Maps, eu adiciono todos os pontos como marcadores no mapa e coloco a posição da câmera para o centro dos pontos.

```
pontos = [[23,13], [11, 45], ..., [22, 21]];

for (let p of pontos) {
    this.map.addMarkerSync({
        position: {
            lat: p[0],
            lng: p[1]
        }
    });
}
```

O problema é que o zoom não permite que todos os pontos sejam visualizados. Minha dúvida é: como calculo o zoom de forma que apareça todos os pontos adicionados?

Comment: Você já tentou calcular de alguma forma? Seria bom colocar o seu código para a gente ter uma noção de como ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Crie um LatLngBounds que inclua todos o pontos.

Use `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds bounds, int padding)` para obter um CameraUpdate que fará a câmara mostrar o LatLngBounds centrado na tela, aplicando o maior zoom possível.

Use esse CameraUpdate no método `animateCamera()` do Map.

A terminologia usada é para Android Java. Suponho que exista o equivalente em Ionic/javascript.

Answer (score -1):

```
var myLatLng = {lat: -23.584460, lng: -46.718901};
          this.map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: myLatLng,
          zoom: 9,
          icon: this.image
        });
}
```

usava esse zoom e dava para ver tudo, aproximar e voltar

Comment: Esse zoom é muito grande. Esses pontos podem estar cada um em uma cidade diferente, ou cada um em um estado diferente, ou todos dentro do mesmo bairro. Não tenho como prever, por isso um valor fixo de zoom não funciona.

Comment: Nao entendi, para voce visualizar todos, precisara de um zoom grande e quando achar o que voce esta procurando voce deve aumentar o zoom nele, nao?

desculpe nao conseguir ajudar

Comment: Eu quero visualizar todos, não quero focar em uma só. Só que quando os pontos são em vários estados preciso de um zoom pequeno, quando os pontos são na mesma cidade preciso de um zoom grande.